# relative pronoun usage: "..., not in which ..."?

Tags: relative-clauses, subject-verb-inversion, relative-pronouns

> 1. There's the room; **not** in the room is the man.

I want to replace the semicolon with a comma and make the second sentence a relative clause. Is it okay to change it as:

> 2. There's the room, **not in which** is the man.

Surely, it's obvious that it would be perfectly grammatical to change it as:

> 3. There's the room, **in which** the man **isn't**.

However, I want to kind of put some emphasis on *not*.
In this case, which sentence would be more acceptable or appropriate?

Comment: There is the room the man is *not* in. / There is the room the man isn't in.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Grammatically, # 2 is fine, but stylistically, it's awkward, though whether that matters or not depends on the context in which you're using it.

Answer (score -1):

I think perhaps it should be

> There's the room; the man is not in the room.